# How to set up Apache reverse proxy with proxy authentication?

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf, mod-proxy

I have two application one runs on Apache server, and other one is running on Windows/IIS.

By using VPN I can connect with my first which is running on Apache but I am unable to access my other application which is hosted on Windows/IIS Server.

So I want to use reverse proxy for accessing the application which is running on Windows/IIS Server.

Apache Server ip http://10.101.9.111
Window IIS Server ip http://10.101.9.112

So what I really want that when in enter http://10.101.9.111/hrms the url automatically load application which is actually available and running on  http://10.101.9.112/hrms.

I have made changes in apache httpd.conf file.

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy /hrms>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
<Location /hrms>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all

    ProxyPass http://10.100.6.119/hrms/
    ProxyPassReverse http://10.100.6.119/hrms/

    RequestHeader unset Authorization
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "businessHr"
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile c:\tmp\users
    Require valid-user

</Location>
```